# Mocking static method in same Class (Mockery, Laravel9)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am writing a unittest for a Laravel project.

I would like to test the public method testMethod() in the following class.

```php
class Foo extends Model
{
    public static function staticMethod($arg)
    {
         return 'from staticMethod';
    }
    public function testMethod($arg)
    {
         $result = self::staticMethod($arg);
         return $result;
    }
}
```

Here is my test code:

---

Edit 2

Following @matiaslauriti 's advice, I rewrote the test code as follows

```
//I did not use 'overload:'. When I used it, I got the error 'testMethod() does not exist on this mock object' (even with makePartial).

$mock = \Mockery::mock(Foo::class)->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('staticMethod')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn('mocked return value');

$this->app->instance(Foo::class, $mock);
 
$mockedFoo = app(Foo::class);

$result = $mockedFoo->testMethod('test argument');
```

Then I changed self:: to static:: as advised.

```
public function testMethod($arg)
    {
         return static::staticMethod($arg);
    }
```

When we did so, the test ran successfully and we were able to mock the static methods!!!!!

---

Edit 1

Following @Charlie's advice, I rewrote the test code as follows

```
 $mock = \Mockery::mock(Foo::class);
 $mock->shouldReceive('staticMethod')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn('mocked return value');

 $this->app->instance(Foo::class, $mock);
 
 $mockedFoo = app(Foo::class);

 $result = $mockedFoo->testMethod('test argument');
```

Here's one question.

```
// return 'mocked return value'
$mockedFoo->staticMethod('test');

// return value of original method.
Foo::staticMethod('test');
```

In the code under test, I am calling it with `Foo::staticMethod()`, not an instance.

I'm still trying this code, but is it possible to mock a statich method without overloading?

And this test returns;

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_2_App_Models_Foo::testMethod(), but no expectations were specified

This error means that the mock recognizes `testMethod()` (I'm glad!).

But I want `testMethod()` to work according to the original code, so I don't want to set a return value for the mock.

So, I used `makePartial()`.

```php
$mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:'.Foo::class)->makePartial();
```

Then, from now on, the `staticMethod()` mock was not used when running the test, but the original `staticMethod()` was used...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there, your issue with the new code is that you are not asking for partial mock, so whatever you have not mocked, will return an error (not defined). But you also need to still overload.

I will share a solution, a quick fix for your code:

```php
$mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:'.Foo::class)->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('staticMethod')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn('mocked return value');

$this->app->instance(Foo::class, $mock);
 
$mockedFoo = app(Foo::class); // This part makes no sense on the test, as you already have the $mock, so directly call the mock

$result = $mockedFoo->testMethod('test argument');
```

But your original code needs to be changed, instead of `self::staticMethod($arg)`, it must be `static::staticMethod($arg)` so when `Mockery` overloads the `Foo` class so it can simulate the static call, `static` refers to the late binding (`Mockery` is doing something like `MockeryClass1 extends Foo`, so if you have `self`, it will always refer to `Foo`, so no mock, but `static` will always refer to `MockeryClass1` in this case, so the static mocked method will work).

So, in code terms, Mockery does something like this:

```php
// When you do this
$mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:'.Foo::class)->makePartial();

// Mockery does something like
class Mocker_class_fake_1 extends Foo
{
    // ...

    public function __call()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function __callStatic()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

/**
 * So when you do $mock->shouldReceive('xyz') and then $mock->xyz()
 * Mockery will use PHP __call ($this->method) magic method to resolve
 * what to do.
 *
 * __callStatic does the same but for static calls. (Class::method)
 * 
 * Having makePartial() does the same, only that will use original code
 * instead of erroring that there is no definition for that method call.
 */
```

Now, if you code is:

```php
public function testMethod($arg)
{
    return self::staticMethod($arg);
}
```

When using that `Mocker_class_fake_1` example class, `self` resolves to `Foo` ALWAYS, but `static` resolves to the one extending and calling that method, in this case `Mocker_class_fake_1::staticMethod($arg)` and then `__callStatic` will be able to resolve `staticMethod` because you wrote `shouldReceive('staticMethod')`, etc.

But you need the 3 things:

- `overload:`.Foo::class
- `makePartial()`
- `$this->app->instance(Foo::class, $mock);` and `app(Foo::class);` (or `resolve(Foo::class);`, exact alias of `app(...)`)

My question would be why are you extending a Model and testing it, usually you do not mix this (of course you can, but that is a bad practice). So I would create a new domain class and separate the Model logic from the Domain logic, but I am not sure why you have it that way as you just put example code, not real code.

Hope this clarifies more!

More info about [`__call`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) and [`__callStatic`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic).

Comment: Thank you so much @matiaslauriti !!   I followed your advice and rewrote it and was able to run the test successfully! (I have included the rewritten code in Edit2 of the post.) Thank you for sharing so much with us. I just have one more question. Is the change to "static::staticMethod()" required in this case? (My editing privileges are limited to test code only, so I was hoping to handle this with just testing as much as possible.)

Comment: Since the real code extends Model, I used it as is as a sample. Yes, I will be careful. Thank you!

Comment: You have to use `static` else the test will never pass, it is just for the test

Comment: My apologies, sir. I've marked it;)    "else the test will never pass " I understand very well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Two of your test contains same issue, you didn't use Laravel app to get the instantiated class, when you use `new Foo()`, it actually instantiated a real **Foo::class** instead of the mocked class.

An untested example：

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(Foo::class);

$mock->shouldReceive('staticMethod')->once()->with('test argument')->andReturn('mocked return value');

// This line will replace the origin Foo::class with the mocked Foo::class.
$this->app->instance(Foo::class, $mock);

// $foo = new Foo(); Instantiate like this won't use the mocked Foo::class.

// Use "app(Foo::class)" to instantiate the mocked class.
$mockedFoo = $this->app(Foo::class);

$result = $mockedFoo->testMethod('test argument');`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thanks also for the explanation, there was a lot I didn't know.

I have just tried your code,
I got the following error.

Received Mockery_2_App_Models_Foo::testMethod(), but no expectations were specified

I think this is because the shouldReceive is not set. But, I want to use the original method without mocking testMethod().  

If you don't mind, could you please let us know how we can help?

Comment: @anko That's not an error, if you're not defined a function in shouldReceive but still called, Mockery will throw an exception to tell you, this is used to prevent unexpected function calls.

Comment: About "I want to use the original method without mocking testMethod()", please gives some test case or I don't know what's your real expect.

Comment: Thank you again. I meant that I did not want to mock because the method under test is testMethod().  Sorry if I did not understand the purpose of your question.

Comment: @anko Sorry, I can't get it... If you don't want to use mockery just need to remove all the code about, and use `$foo = new Foo()`, `$foo->testMethod('test argument');` like your origin code before.

Comment: Sorry I can't explain it better, thank you again and again!